# Matching abbreviated first names using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match the name `R. Buckminster Fuller` in a wikipedia dump that has

`|name = R. Buckminster Fuller`

and I have the following regular expression:

`(?<=[n|N]ame = )[\w\W\.\s]+?(?=[^A-Za-z0-9_\s])`

It doesn't seem to work - it gets hung on the period after the R. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `^` in your regex. it doesn't make sense. inside the [] it indicates exclusion of following characters.

wouldn't this do?

```
[n|N]ame = ([\w\.\s]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your regular expression, it's not really clear what you want to do.

The following expression match the full name :

```
(?<=[n|N]ame = )[\w\W\.\s]+
```

But without more informations about your goal, it's impossible for me to help you further.

For information, the +? modifier is a "lazy match" and will match the fewest character possible, in our case only the 'R'.